# how to filter out rows in data frame and take the sum

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas
I have a dataframe and it has three columns with values as

```
nTimeStamp       nMessageCode   nIOC
1544114048       12073           0
1544114048       12075           0         
1544114048       12073           1
1544114048       12075           1
1544114049       12074           0         
1544114049       12073           0
1544114049       12075           0
```

I want to get the sum as per the nTimeStamp based on the filter as below

SQL code

```
SELect nTimeStamp, SUM(nFilter) nCount
 FROM (
Select nTimeStamp case when nMessageCode in (12073,12074)
                       then 1
                       when nMessageCode = 12075 and nIOC = 0
                       then 1
                       else 0
                   end 'nFilter'   
      )
 group by nTimeStamp
```

expected result will be

```
nTimestamp       nCount
1544114048         3
1544114049         3
```

How do I achieve the same. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Create boolean mask and count `True` values by [`Series.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) with `sum`:

```
m = (df['nMessageCode'].isin((12073,12074)) | 
     (df['nMessageCode'].eq(12075) & df['nIOC'].eq(0)))

df1 = m.groupby(df['nTimeStamp']).sum().astype(int).reset_index(name='nCount')
print (df1)
   nTimeStamp  nCount
0  1544114048       3
1  1544114049       3
```